# Label over lay issue in Materialize

Tags: html, css, materialize

I am working on a project using Materialize. I am facing issue on pre-filled values in text box. 
Below is the screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

```
<div class="input-field col s12 m6">
   <input class="" id="userNameAccount" type="text" ng-model="userNameAccount" >
      <label class="active" for="">User Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
 </div>





 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        Materialize.updateTextFields();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but this is the solution I found and it worked like a charm to me:

Add a space to the value:

`<input id="userPassword" type="password" class="validate" asp-for="Password" value=" ">`

I found this here: [Solution](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/194)